# External Hard Drive not assigned drive letter on Windows and marked, “Read only”

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, read-only

External Hard Drive not assigned drive letter on Windows and marked, “Read only”

I have an external 2TB drive (Seagate Expansion Desk).  It has 1 partition (NTFS) with valuable files. It was working until my wife plugged a fan in a loose power outlet.  It is now not recognised as a hard drive by Windows Explorer.

I tried running MiniTool Partition Wizard.  Partition Wizard recognises the hard drive as “(Bad Disk)” and “Read Only”.

SeaTools for Windows cannot identify the faulty hard drive.

DISKPART.exe can see the hard drive as Disk 4 but cannot provide details as it does not contain a device letter.

I am 71 years and began with an Amiga 500 (SCSI) and then Windows 3.1 on MFM.  I have never had a partition drop out of sight before, so I am at a total loss.  It does seem to me that my first task is to reset the “Read Only” attribute.
Any help you can give will be very much appreciated.  Please note:  I do not have any experience at all with Linux, so if Linux is the answer I will need point by point instructions on what to do.

Some screenshots:

MiniTool Partition Wizard:

[image: MiniTool Partition Wizard]

DiskPart:

[image: DiskPart]

Disk Management:

[image: Disk Management]

Comment: The HDD inside or, more likely, the SATA to USB controller is fried. Or the power supply. Probably nothing that can be solved by software alone.

Comment: MiniTool Power Data Recovery can access raw data.  I will wait for replacement drive before proceeding, then move faulty drive from USB to inside desktop case for secure reading.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick fix for this, and it's simple as well!

Connect your external drive, then open an Elevated Command Promt and type the following:

- diskpart
- list disk
- select disk 3
- attributes disk clean readonly
- exit

And you shall have access your files again! Good Luck!